# Data passed to another page with SQL Server compact in WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I have passed my data to another page but the output is not the one i wanted. It displayed PhoneApp.ToDoList instead of the specific data. Below is my code:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    private void MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // If selected item is null (no selection) do nothing
        if (MLongListSelector.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var select_Item = MLongListSelector.SelectedItem;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ToDoDetailPage.xaml?Select_Item=" + select_Item, UriKind.Relative));


        // Navigate to the new page
        //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ToDoDetailPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected item to null (no selection)
        MLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Retrieved on ToDoDetailPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Select_Item")) 
        { 
            Title.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["Select_Item"]; 
        }


    }
```

Here is the image for the breakpoint of var select_Item = MLongListSelector.SelectedItem; in MainPage.xaml.cs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your selected_Item. Because in navigation URL, it is passed as string. So you should pass the param you need,like (selected_Item as someClass).someProperty

Comment: The problem is I dont know what is that someClass.someProperty should be. I have also tried string select_Item = MLongListSelector.SelectedItem; but same result appear

Comment: someClass.someProperty. It depends on what data source did your control binded.

Comment: Can you kindly guide me on that? What do i need to do to search for that?

Comment: Because I am on my phone. So I can't write code now. You can search longlistselector, databind, selectchanged, page navigation and so on. It will help to you.

Comment: If you could use a laptop whenever you are free please do because I am still new in this field and not sure of what I am suppose to do. Thanks

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for your tips on what I should do! I have found the solution. This is what I changed (MLongListSelector.SelectedItem as PhoneApp.ToDoList).Title;

Comment: Yeah,it's great.I am so happy to help you.